# Is it possible to open cursor which is in package in another procedure?

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor, toad

Just a thought,Is it possible to open cursor which is in package in another procrdure?

example : pack_name has a procedure myprocedure. The cursor opened in this procedure can be opened in another procedure ? 
i.e can OPEN LV_TEST_CUR FOR LV_QUERY; be written in another procedure ?

```
create or replace package pack_name
is 
create or replace 
PROCEDURE myprocedure
AS
  LV_TEST_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
  LV_QUERY VARCHAR2(200);
  LV_DATE  DATE;
BEGIN
  LV_QUERY:='select sysdate as mydate from dual';



END myprocedure;
end pack_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to? It doesn't really make sense to define the query used for a ref cursor in one package's procedure and then to open it in a completely different package's procedure.

Sure it's possible (although your attempt won't work) - you'd just be passing around the string containing the select statement you want to use to open your ref cursor - but it's not the best design. For a start, you're now stuck using dynamic sql, when you might otherwise have been able to open the ref cursor with static sql (dynamic sql is only checked at runtime, not at compile time, so you won't know about any syntax errors until you try to open the cursor).

In general, I would stick to opening the ref cursor in the same place as it was defined.